# While updating product using OROCommerce API we are getting error "This form should not contain extra fields"

Tags: php, api, rest, orocrm, orocommerce

Hi all we are sending patch request to orocommerce using php curl :

URL : url http://oro.demo/commerce/public/admin/api/products/71

Data as :

> {"data":{"type":"products","id":"70","attributes":{"sku":"10305","status":"enabled","variantFields":[],"productType":"simple","featured":true,"newArrival":false},"relationships":{"attributeFamily":{"data":{"type":"attributefamilies","id":"1"}},"inventory_status":{"data":{"type":"prodinventorystatuses","id":"in_stock"}},"names":{"data":[{"type":"localizedfallbackvalues","id":"names-1"}]},"primaryUnitPrecision":{"data":{"type":"productunitprecisions","id":"product-unit-precision-id-3"}}}},"included":[{"type":"productunitprecisions","id":"product-unit-precision-id-3","attributes":{"precision":"7","conversionRate":"5","sell":"0"},"relationships":{"unit":{"data":{"type":"productunits","id":"set"}}}},{"type":"localizedfallbackvalues","id":"names-1","attributes":{"fallback":null,"string":"Fruit Oatmeal","text":null},"relationships":{"localization":{"data":null}}}]}

**in Response we are getting result error .**

> [{"title":"extra fields constraint","detail":"This form should not contain extra fields: "{"data":{"type":"products","id":"70","attributes":{"sku":"10305","status":"enabled","variantFields":"."}]

same data work in sandbox and postman as shown in attachment
[image]

Comment: pls explain better your problem and format the code to let us help you

Comment: Pass postman screen capture there

Comment: using sandbox same above data work fine

Comment: I am sharing postman screen

Comment: Hi @Developer will you please check shared screen capture of postman

Answer (score 2):

My issue resolved by adding Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json.

Thank you all